# How to download files from a url using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell. I need to download log files from a URL address.  The folder has multiple files for each day.  The generic format of the file name is plus_220919030001.csv (yymmddhhmmss.csv).  I've not been able to find any way to do this. If I use the exact file name I have been able to use Invoke-RestMethod but I need to get multiple files and I don't know the filenames.

Comment: Unless the web service you're talking to provides a way to request a file listing, I don't see how this can be done, short of using brute force to iterate over all possible   time values in a day. What service are you talking to, and does its documentation not indicate how to ask for a file listing?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would think about it would be Invoke-WebRequest the url with the folders into a variable and then iterate through them. A really basic test example on a local file system would be something like

```
$files = Get-ChildItem
foreach ($file in $files) {Write-Output $file.Name}
```

which would get you the listing as an object you can iterate through. Just replace Get-ChildItem with your Invoke, and Write-Output with something useful to do with each in the loop.